# Gravitatinal Dipole moments?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, dipole-moment, multipole-expansion

So, I was reading about electric dipoles, which is a system of positive and negative charges kept at a distance $d$.

But I got an ideas, as to why there seems to be a lot of example of electric dipoles, but not of **gravitational** dipoles. Atleast I haven't seen in my textbook. If two msses are kept at some distance, can they be called gravitational dipole?

So, do they even exist? What about binary star systems? Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: Seems like it would need two opposite poles (positive and negative) to be a true analogue, which gravity does not have

Comment: You are talking of the geometrical definition of dipole, and it does exist, in gravity the same type of "charge". In this answer there are links for how gravitational waves are generated given the geometric status of the mass https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/639074/